Possible to tune a MCU with XCP on Ethernet over ESP32 (Wireless/Bluetooth)
I'm a beginner working with the iMXRT106x chip which in Simulink (Embedded Coder) supports XCP Ethernet Inferface and I'd like to tune the device/software (INCA, ATI Express, CANape) wirelessly using XCP.
Would it be possible to use a ESP32-C device and how could I set it up to reach this target or a there better ways?
Could I create a TCP-Server (or UDP) on the ESP32 with the hope that the XCP-Tuning-Software could connect to the device with XCP on Ethernet, but then have the communication between the MCU and ESP32 as UART?
Would this be best with WiFi or is bluetooth better?
No attempts yet.  Trying to understand if my aim is technically (and easily) achievable
